# const definition doubts

Tags: c++

Does it make any difference to define something as

```
const string msg=_T("serious");
const string& msg=_T("serious");
```

and

```
string const msg=_T("serious");
string const&msg=_T("serious");
```

Thank you

Comment: You must not use `_T()` if you're storing the string literal in a `std::string`. Similarly, you must just use `L"serious"` if you're storing the result in a `std::wstring`. You should only use `_T()` if you're defined a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` (aka `tstring`) yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **No difference** both of them are same. It is just different style of saying so.

Comment: Thank Als, but could you help me prove it ?

Comment: @Baby Dolphin: Yes, Use it in your program in either way and You will see no difference in the output/result of your program.

Comment: @Baby Dolphin: Read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.8.

Comment: In this case the response of the compiler is important, not the input/output behaviour of the program.
Just write some test code whicht ries to modify the const strings from your example.

Comment: const string msg1=_T("serious");   const string& msg2=_T("serious");  Will msg2 reference msg1 or share its address or both are totally different ? I learnt in school the same string value means variables are shared their addresses.

Comment: @Baby Dolphin: Two strings having the **same value** does **not mean** they are stored in **same memory locations**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `const string` and `string const`.

`const string msg` creates `msg` object in local scope. This is what you should do.

`const string& msg` creates a reference which is initialized with temporary object. Here, lifetime of the temporary object is prolonged until `msg` goes out of scope, so it's ok, but in other expressions it may be a error or undefined behavior. If you drop `const`, the definition will no longer be valid. You shouldn't use this.

You do not need `_T()` here, as `string` will not turn into wstring in Unicode builds.

Comment: Thank you, I use Windows Programming book by Jeff Richter quite often (but only back and forth the first few chapters to learn simple programs with dialogs), it becomes a habit then. I'takk your point and am sorry for inconvenience.